# PHP only allow UTF-8 chars and spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to validate a string in PHP using regex; it can only contain letters (including latin letters such as 'á', 'õ', etc) and spaces.

Using `preg_replace('/\P{L}/u', '', $ str);` I get rid of everything (including the spaces) but the latin letters. What do I need to change on the regex to include the spaces as well?

Comment: maybe if you negate the negation: `[^\pL ]` match anything that is not no letter in any language or a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s]+/u', '', $str);
```

The `[^\p{L}\s]+` pattern will match 1 or more occurrences of any char but a Unicode letter or whitespace. Note that due to `u` modifier, `\s` will recognize any Unicode whitespace chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/anqNdw/1).

**Details**

- `[^` - start of a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char but

  - `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
  - `\s` - whitespace
- `]+`  - 1 or more times.

If you have diacritics and want to keep them, you will have to add `\p{M}` to the negated character class, `/[^\p{L}\p{M}\s]+/u`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I use this same regex with JS? I tried `value.match('/[^\p{L}\s]+/u')` in which `value` is `***` but it returns `null`

Comment: @fpicoral If you only want to support Crome or any other JS environment supporting ECMAScript 2018, use `value.replace(/[^\p{L}\s]+/gu, '')`. In older standards, try `value.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]+/g, '')` (they do not support `\p{L}`). Or, see [equivalents here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668315/3832970).